# Can resources of different stages be included in one azure purview?

Tags: azure-purview

I want to put all non-production resources in one purview instead of creating three purviews for DEV, SIT and UAT, like:

[image]

Is this possible? Or is it a meaningless idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can include resources from various stages in one Azure Purview. Azure Purview is designed to enable you to create a single, holistic, up-to-date map of your data landscape, whether it is on-premises, across clouds, or in SaaS applications.

If your goal is to have a single view of all your resources across different stages, then yes, you can do so. You can group resources by assigning them to different classifications in Azure Purview. This helps you to organize resources and apply policies and governance rules to the appropriate data. This can help you manage various stages within the same Purview. But if you want to segregate access, permissions, or visibility across various stages, then it might be better to have separate Purviews for each stage.